# Which SharePoint 2007 features are not available to Office 2003 users?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office

I have been tasked with coming up with a compatibility guide for SharePoint 2007 comparing Office 2003 and Office 2007. Does anyone know where to find such a list?

I have been searching for awhile but I cannot seem to find a comprehensive list.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an entire MS white paper on Office integration with SharePoint:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/d/c/5dcfc15a-c31e-4a14-93cf-b44bce3e447e/Microsoft%20Office%20and%20SharePoint%20Integration%20White%20Paper.doc

Answer (score 1):

This post might be helpful: http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2008/08/office-2003-and-sharepoint-2007-comparision